# pecl_http make: *** [php_http.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed

Tags: php, pcre, pecl

I have looked around quite a bit to see if I could correct the problem I am experiencing with installing pecl_http on a RHEL 6.5 system.   I haven't found anything that is relevant.

Everything looks good until I hit some PCRE work.

Not sure what else to provide / include.

```
downloading pecl_http-2.1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-2.1.0.tgz (158,765 bytes)
..................................done: 158,765 bytes
64 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Enable extended HTTP support [yes] : 
where to find zlib [/usr] : 
where to find libcurl [/usr] : 
where to find libevent [/usr] : 
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0
running: /var/tmp/pecl_http/configure --with-http --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable extended HTTP support... yes, shared
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getdomainname... yes
checking for zlib.h... found in /usr
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.3
checking for curl/curl.h... found in /usr
checking for curl-config... found: /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for curl version >= 7.18.2... 7.19.7
checking for SSL support in libcurl... yes
checking for openssl support in libcurl... no
checking for gnutls support in libcurl... no
checking for ares support in libcurl... no
checking for bundled SSL CA info... /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
checking for event2/event.h... not found
configure: WARNING: continuing without libevent support
checking for ext/raphf support... yes
checking for php_raphf.h... /usr/include/php/ext/raphf
checking for ext/propro support... yes
checking for php_propro.h... /usr/include/php/ext/propro
checking whether to depend on extensions which have been built shared... yes
checking for ext/hash support... yes
checking for php_hash.h... /usr/include/php/ext/hash
checking for ext/json support... yes
checking for ext/iconv support... yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/hash... yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/iconv... yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/json... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/main -I/var/tmp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php/ext/raphf -I/usr/include/php/ext/propro -I/usr/include/php/ext/hash  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/pecl_http/php_http_buffer.c -o php_http_buffer.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/var/tmp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/main -I/var/tmp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php/ext/raphf -I/usr/include/php/ext/propro -I/usr/include/php/ext/hash -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/pecl_http/php_http_buffer.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_http_buffer.o
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/main -I/var/tmp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php/ext/raphf -I/usr/include/php/ext/propro -I/usr/include/php/ext/hash  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/pecl_http/php_http.c -o php_http.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/var/tmp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootpJvU1a/pecl_http-2.1.0/main -I/var/tmp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php/ext/raphf -I/usr/include/php/ext/propro -I/usr/include/php/ext/hash -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/pecl_http/php_http.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_http.o
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
                 from /var/tmp/pecl_http/php_http_api.h:29,
                 from /var/tmp/pecl_http/php_http.c:13:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
                 from /var/tmp/pecl_http/php_http_api.h:29,
                 from /var/tmp/pecl_http/php_http.c:13:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre’
make: *** [php_http.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this error is given in compilation because you do not have the necessary PCRE libraries in place. Try:

```
apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

or

```
yum install pcre-devel
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't work for me. Anything else it might be?

Comment: Hard to tell, this question is over a year old and things may have changed. Might want to ask a new question with the log output so people can see what may be going on.

Comment: Yeh I was in the process of writing a newer question, then I found there was a newer version of 1.* that I'd been trying to install (previously v1.6.4) `pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6` installed OK for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice this person was trying for v2.*, sorry. I think they are quite incompatible. Oh well.

Comment: Ah ok, no worries. Good luck.